# How to create a simple divider in the new NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-design-library, navigationview

Google introduced the `NavigationView` in the Design Support Library version 22.2.0 with which you can create a drawer very easily using a menu resource.

How can I create a simple divider line between two items? Grouping the items didn't work. Creating a sub items section does create a divider line, but it requires a title, which I don't want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As stated in the comments to it, the problem with the accepted answer is, that the checkable behavior doesn't work across multiple (parallel) groups.
To avoid this, do not create parallel groups, but use sub menus or sub groups to get your dividers as described in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766919/how-to-set-shared-checkable-behavior-across-all-groups-in-navigationview/33877051#33877051

Answer (score 338, accepted):

All you need to do is define a `group` with an **unique ID**. I have checked the implementation, and if groups have different ids, it will create a divider.

### Example menu, creating the separator:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: i upvoted it @Nilesh , i just want to get information, that what is NavigationView,? and is it like Navigation Drawer? can you give information..just want to know

Comment: Yes @AjayP.Prajapati you can always check this blog for new things in android  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Wonder why this is (as far as I know) not documented. I think it will be asked a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The one problem with this approach is that `setChecked` seems to work at the group level. If you select an item in Group A, then open the drawer again and select item in Group B, both items will remain highlighted. Maybe Google will fix this behavior in the next release, but for now, that's the downside of using multiple groups with NavigationView.

Comment: @hungryghost yes this is just preview, definitely Google will fixed it

Comment: @hungryghost you can manually unselect items in a listener as a workaround

Comment: Set `<dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>` to remove the padding when you do this unless you want each group to have padding.

Comment: Great. About the double checked, try `android:checkableBehavior="none"` for your second group (that are actions, not navigation, I assume)

Comment: how to add selected BG color?

Comment: problem with this is when we are marking the item as checked, the bg for checked item doesn`t shows from one separator to other. empty space is shown which looks bad

Comment: Update :
adding <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
in dimens.xml solves the issue. Yay !

Comment: Funny thing, if you remove the id from the `group` it will compile and run but the dividers are hidden.

Comment: divider adds extra padding. how to remove that padding?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa  see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519293/reduce-space-between-menu-groups-inside-navigation-drawer/38519594#38519594

Comment: This does not work for me either. I wanted lines between the menu groups, not after each item.

Comment: Does not work for me, it just add checkbox for each item, not divider.

Comment: How to adjust gaps between Icon and the Title for the items ?

Comment: I can't believe this is the selected answer with a lot of upvotes. It's so hacky.

Answer (score 62):

create a drawable ***drawer_item_bg.xml*** like this,

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#F4F4F4" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#EAEAEA" />
        </shape>
        <!--
        android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                -->
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and add it to NavigationView as ***app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"***

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F4F4F4"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"/>
```

and here we go...[image]

Comment: this works, but it also removes the left padding of item icon. at least in my code, not in your screenshot for some reason

Comment: @vbp I need the top border for first child, bottom border for other child. How could I achieve. It is something similar to id.first child in css

Comment: @Prabs consider using a fragment ,recyclerview or custom views instead of NavigationView for better customization

Comment: I've done `navMenuView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(NavigationViewActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));` for perfect item border

Answer (score 24):

You can add dividers easily by setting Menu Item Background via XML using `app:itemBackground`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@id/drawer_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/all_navigation_menu"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/bg_drawer_item"
    android:background="@color/default_background"/>
```

And use **LayerDrawable** as the background. It preserves material design ripple overlay for clicks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/divider"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: seems to be the best answer and no group involved

Comment: What if you want to use a custom background color for the selected item?

Comment: I have an error on <shape>: Element is not allowed here

Answer (score 20):

Simple add DividerItemDecoration :

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
NavigationMenuView navMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
navMenuView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

It looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Can I change the height of `addItemDecoration` line to 1px?

Comment: Thank you your solution worked for me. I appreciate. Bro one more question with this. Is it possible to remove the top border for the first item and set borders only to the bottom of the items?

Comment: @viper please refer this : https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/

Comment: That kind of divider for each item not follow Material Guyidelines

Answer (score 11):

I think I have an even better solution for the problem of multiple checked items. Using my way you don't have to worry about changing your code when adding new sections to your menu.
My menu looks just like the accepted solution written by Jared, with the difference of using andoid:checkableBehavior="**all**" on the groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/first_section" android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/frontpage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home_24dp_light_blue"
            android:title="@string/drawer_frontpage" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/drawer_search" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/second_section" android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/events"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_maps_local_movies_24dp_light_blue"
            android:title="@string/drawer_events" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The checkableBehavior of 'all' makes it possible to check/uncheck single items at will, independently from which group they belong to. You just have to store the last checked menuitem. The java-code looks like this:

```
private MenuItem activeMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Update selected/deselected MenuItems
    if (activeMenuItem != null)
        activeMenuItem.setChecked(false);
    activeMenuItem = menuItem;
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is fixed in `API 26 (Android 8)` or it was possible all the time. I'm still a noob in Android programming. However I added parent groups as below. Testing on Android 6 physical phone,

1. I have the divider
2. Selecting any item from either `nav_g1` or `nav_g2` will deselect other items.
3. No extra padding added due to nested groups.
4. I didn't add any `Java` code to listeners

**Menu Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <group
            android:id="@+id/nav_g1"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_2"/>
        </group>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/nav_g2"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_3"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_4"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_4"/>
        </group>
    </group>
    <item android:title="Actions">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_7"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_7"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_8"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/nav_8"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**Notes**

1. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605906/1041046) answer each group need to have a unique Id to show the divider.
2. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30585374/1041046) answer spaces are matching the google material design specs.
3. Having `android:checkableBehavior="single"` for parent group is required so the problem of multiple selected menu items in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625471/1041046) answer (mentioned in comments by hungryghost) does not happen

And here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the device screen]

Answer (score 8):

Making different groups like Nilesh's answer does make a divider in between But 
creates the problem of two checked items in the nav drawer.

A simple way how I handled this was:

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {

    //if an item from extras group is clicked,refresh NAV_ITEMS_MAIN to remove previously checked item
    if (menuItem.getGroupId() == NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA) {


        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_MAIN, false, true);
        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA, true, true);
       }else{

        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_MAIN, true, true);
        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA, false, true);


    }
    //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `android:checkableBehavior="none"`

Comment: @espinchi - That will not work if other groups contain navigation menu items. This solution could work for actions only. Not good UX practice

Comment: Excellent!  It might be clearer if you changed your undefined constants NAV_ITEMS_MAIN and NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA with R.id.nav_items_group_main or R.id.nav_items_group_extra and add the required XML to your example

Comment: IS onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) { Default method?? where should i do this code?

Comment: and what is NAV_ITEMS_MAIN??

Comment: @John - Yes, it is the default implemented method of NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
NAV_ITEMS_MAIN is just the R.id. of the menuItem's group,eg: in menu.xml its R.id.groupIdMain

Comment: @ZorawarSachdev Thank you so much default method is very clear i have implemented it. Another doubt is <group id == NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA and items id = NAV_ITEMS_MAIN is that right??

i have four items in the same group how i will add the line ?

Comment: With Support Library 23.1.0 this fix is no longer needed at all. Setting android:checkableBehavior="single" in both groups keeps only one item checked from both groups.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted dividers above the first item and after the last item. Using @Nilesh solution I had to add dummy menu items and set enabled to false which felt really dirty. Plus what if I want to do other cool stuff in my menu?

I noticed the NavigationView extends FrameLayout so you can put your own content into it just like you would for a FrameLayout. I then set an empty menu xml so that it only shows my custom layout. I understand that this probably goes against the path Google wants us to take but if you want a truly custom menu this is an easy way to do it.

```
<!--Note: NavigationView extends FrameLayout so we can put whatever we want in it.-->
<!--I don't set headerLayout since we can now put that in our custom content view-->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/empty_menu">

    <!--CUSTOM CONTENT-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- CUSTOM HEADER -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/vNavigationViewHeader"
            layout="@layout/navigation_view_header"/>

        <!--CUSTOM MENU-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vNavigationViewHeader">

            <View style="@style/NavigationViewLineSeperator"/>

            <Button android:text="Option 1"/>

            <View style="@style/NavigationViewLineSeperator"/>

            <Button android:text="Option 2"/>

            <View style="@style/NavigationViewLineSeperator"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Here is the style

```
<style name="NavigationViewLineSeperator">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/line_seperator</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
</style>
```

And drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <size android:width="100sp"
          android:height="1sp" />
</shape>
```

And the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</menu>
```

edit:

Instead of Buttons you can use TextView with drawable which mimics the original menu items look:

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="@string/menu_support"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/menu_icon_support"
     style="@style/MainMenuText" />

// style.xml
<style name="MainMenuText">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, apparently the most convenient way of having custom views as menu items

Comment: i use this solution also because it lets me more easy set the custom font of  items and change the divider color

Answer (score 1):

*Credit should go to Zorawar for the solution, Sorry for duplicating the answer but could not add so much formatted text within a comment.*

Zorawar's solution works, the code could be improved as such :

```
public void onNavigationItemSelected(int groupId) {

    //if an item from extras group is clicked,refresh NAV_ITEMS_MAIN to remove previously checked item
    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_MAIN, (groupId == NAV_ITEMS_MAIN), true);
    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA, (groupId == NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA), true);


    //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: what is NAV_ITEMS_MAIN and NAV_ITEMS_EXTRA and groupid??

Comment: They are constants for the group_id

Answer (score 1):

Call requires API level 28 :

just use

```
 menu?.setGroupDividerEnabled(true)
```

in onCreateOptionsMenu function

Example :

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            menu?.setGroupDividerEnabled(true)
        }
        
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nileh's Answer is right , Except it has one flaw of double checking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/grp1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_register_customer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:checkableBehavior="none"
            android:title="Register Customer" />
    </group>
    <group  android:id="@+id/grp2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"  >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:checkableBehavior="none"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

So using

> android:checkableBehavior="single"

with unique id shall solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add divider **dynamically**, you can just add an empty SubMenu like this:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.addSubMenu(" ").add(" ");
```

this will add a divider.

just be sure to pass in the right index when using `menu.getItem(int index)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers if you do want decorative separators but don't want to create multiple groups because of "checkable behavior" problems - you can assign the same group id to all your groups.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_nav_common" <!-- New group id-->
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_main" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_nav_articles"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_art_track_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/latest_news" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_nav_group_categories"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_sections">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@id/group_nav_common" <!-- Existing group id -->
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <!-- Programmatically populated section -->
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_nav_group_sites"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_sites">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@id/group_nav_common" <!-- Existing group id -->
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_nav_select_site"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black_24dp"
                    android:title="@string/nav_menu_select_site" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the selected answer not work for you, you may want to try adding this to `onCreateOptionsMenu` in addition to give the unique group id:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
    menu.setGroupDividerEnabled(true)
}
```