# Divider in Navigation Drawer using a xml menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I've been following the latest (?) [tutorial of how to implement a Material Design Navigation Drawer](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) side by side [with this blogpost.](http://blog.grafixartist.com/easy-navigation-drawer-with-design-support-library/)

Instead of populating a list view it uses a menu resource (xml). Very neat and easy, but..

I can't figure out how to add dividers between menu items. 
Image from Material Design spec:
[image]

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
         android:id="@+id/item_1"
         android:checked="true"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
         android:title="Item1"
      />
      <item
         android:id="@+id/item_2"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
         android:title="Item2"
      />
      <item
         android:id="@+id/item_3"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
         android:title="Item3"
      />
      <item
         android:id="@+id/item_4"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
         android:title="Item4"
      />
   </group>
</menu>
```

I have tried dividing by groups, but it gives me no divider. When I added a submenu, I got a divider but also an unwanted header.

Like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/item_1"
      android:checked="true"
      android:title="Header1"
    >
      <menu>
        <item
          android:id="@+id/item_2"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
          android:title="SubItem1"
        />
      </menu>
    </item>
    <item
      android:id="@+id/item_2"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
      android:title="Item2"
    />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/item_3"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
      android:title="Item3"
    />
    <item
       android:id="@+id/item_4"
       android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
       android:title="Item4"
    />
  </group>
</menu>
```

[image]

I want the divider, but not the header. 
Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can try by putting empty title for 2nd group item.

Comment: Hi, not sure what is the '2nd group item' (you have both unique ids and titles in the code, please refer to that =) ). I've tried having empty `title` in the Header1 but it will still push the menu down and leave allocated area for the title.

Comment: For that you can use custom listview.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview

Comment: Solution: You get dividers between groups if, and only if, you give the groups id attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a divider after each *menu item* provide unique `id` to each *group item* as shown below

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_item_1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_agreement"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Agreement" />
</group>
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_item_2"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_aboutus"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="About Us" />
</group>
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_item_3"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Terms Condition  " />
</group>
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_item_4"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chngpassword"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Change Password" />
</group>
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_item_5"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_signout"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Sign Out" />
</group>
```

Comment: Thank you! The trick is to put `android:id` for the `<group>` . Otherwise, the dividers wont appear.

Comment: how to change divider color for the <group>