# Draw line between menu items

Tags: android, menu

I am not using a navigation drawer . 
I only am using a menu.xml and i want to draw a line separating between these items. 
I am sure that the line is drawn but i think its color is white so i cannot see it , how can i change its color? 
Thank you

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.orangelabs.crypto.blindstorage.android.poc.HomeActivity">


    <group android:checkableBehavior="none"
        android:id="@+id/group1">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_disconnect"
        android:title="@string/action_disconnect"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_upload"
        android:title="@string/action_upload"
        app:showAsAction="never">

    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_chiffre"
            android:title="@string/action_chiffre"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_non_chiffre"
            android:title="@string/action_non_chiffre"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
</item>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_folder"
        android:title="@string/action_create_folder"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none"
        android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_logs"
            android:title="@string/a_propos"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </group>


</menu>
```

Comment: This menu is part of Action Bar or Navigation Drawer ?

Comment: this menu is part of an Action Bar

Comment: Try a custom separator line by creating a `view` with `width = match_parent` and `height = 1 or 2`. Sorry i'm not sure this works on `menu`, i have nothing on me now for testing it but may be ;).

Answer (score -3):

```
<View
android:height="1dp"
android:width="match_parent"
android: background="@android:color/grey"
/>
```

This is for navigation drawer, use this code in between the items.

For menu items, check this link:
[How to add line divider for menu item Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011534/how-to-add-line-divider-for-menu-item-android)

Comment: I have tried this as well , using another layout as action_layout , but the divider doesn't seem to appear ....

Answer (score -4):

```
<View
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
/>
```

Use this code inbetween the menu items.

Comment: I get this error: Error:(30, 24) String types not allowed (at 'width' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: Edited. Small mistake. Also I think a gray shade would look better than black.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I do not see any change in my menu