# How to add separator in menu items?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, navigation-drawer

I need to add a separator between `Navigation Drawer` menu items.

Code for `NavigationDrawer`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   android:id="@+id/navigationView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
   custom:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
   custom:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

## drawer_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/com_mixpanel_android_ic_bell"
        android:title="@string/home" />
    <item> </item>
    .....
    </group>
</menu>
```

## Theme

```
 <style name="NavigationTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot of navigation drawe]r

How can I add a separator (View) between two `menu_items`?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview/30625471#30625471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is simple - Separate items into different groups (groups must have assigned **different, unique id's**).

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group 
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item>(...)</item>
    </group>

    <group 
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item>(...)</item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

---

**Edit:**

In your situation, when you need to remove this padding, there are two solutions:

1. Don't use `custom:menu`, create `ListView` instead with adapter and set for your `ListView` and add

   ```
   android:divider="#FFFFFF"
   android:dividerHeight="1px"
   ```
2. This solution may not work, because parameters can be changed by Android Platform Developers:

   Add the following lines to `dimens.xml`

   ```
   <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is taking too much spaces. As you can see the highlighted area is not even filled with whole red color. Any hint how can I correct it. http://i.imgur.com/eOmEQgG.png

Comment: Then there are two options. First one is create `ListView` and adapter for it, instead of menu. Second is easier, but may not work - add to `dimens.xml` following line `<dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>`.

Comment: Yeah I used ListView :)
BTW adding `navigation_separator_vertical_padding"` is not removing the padding

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it helped you a little, you can upvote/mark it as accepted :)