# Reduce space between menu groups inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to reduce the space between each menu group in the **Navigation drawer** (In the following image, space between the two lines).

[image]

I've created a custom style and tried the following attributes

```
<item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
```

They only reduced the padding around the items text.

> Even the following attributes didn't worked

```
<item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
```

Comment: check if you have set margin for these components or not

Comment: I've checked and I didn't set any margin. I've even added the attributes in the styles <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item> and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you must  override 
**design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding** `dimens` in your project **dimes.xml**

```
 <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in **dimens** in your project **dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```