# Can't remove navigation drawer item padding - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application in which I need to have navigation drawer with some items. The problem is that I am unable to reduce padding among the [items in navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6RTG.png). I have searched a lot but nothing worked.

Style.xml

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">10dip</item>
    </style>
```

I also have tried  android:paddingTop but no expected result.

menu.xml

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_pak"
        android:id="@+id/idNavPak"
        android:title="Pakistan" />

    <item
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_world"
        android:id="@+id/idNavWorld"
        android:title="World" />
    <item
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_business"
        android:id="@+id/idNavBusiness"
        android:title="Business" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavSports"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_sports"
        android:title="Sports" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavErtainmentnent"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_entermnt"
        android:title="Entertainment" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavHealth"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_health"
        android:title="Health" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavTv"
        android:icon="@mipmap/live_icon"
        android:title="Live TV"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavDost"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_dost"
        android:title="Dost 32" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavCareers"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_career"
        android:title="Careers" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idNavContactUs"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_contact_us"
        android:title="Contact Us" />
   <!--<item
        android:id="@+id/IdNavSettings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_setting"
        android:title="Settings" />-->
</group>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce space between menu groups inside navigation drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519293/reduce-space-between-menu-groups-inside-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution proposed by gaurav4sarma!

If you still got the same problem, use a custom layout for your navigation drawer items by refering to this link [Android Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/).

Now, you can manage the space and the padding between different subviews!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Image and text is defined in main in which there is menu.xml no image view or text view is defined by me

Comment: Check my new answer :)

Comment: Nothing worked the solution u provided, compels me to modify a long portion of code. any simple solution plz.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `app:itemIconPadding="@dimen/margin_16dp"` in navigation view

Answer (score -1):

This has already been answered here

[Reduce space between menu groups inside navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519293/reduce-space-between-menu-groups-inside-navigation-drawer)

Just go through this class

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L90

Comment: If by simple solution you mean 1 line answer and you not having to go through the documentation i am sorry. This is not why we are here in SO for