# How to add gap between two group menu item?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_profile"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_my_profile"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/view_alertsbadge" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_merge"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_merge"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_merge" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_export"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_export"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_export" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_switch"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_notifications" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/shareapp"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_profile"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_rate" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/blank1">


    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/aboutapps"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_report"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_report"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_report" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_faq"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_faq" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_about" />

    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/blank">


    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_logout" />
    </group>


</menu>
```

this is my navigationmenu.xml using this my screen is  coming like this

[image]

my expected screen is below:

[image]

i have to add gap between each group item or add some padding between each group not each item i.e we have to add gap on divider please see my current screen and expected screen . i tried much but i am unable to to this please suggest me .

Comment: share your code where you insert menu item?

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/rmL4imhkEAiGprA3Ls8N8g here i have added @HemantParmar

Comment: @HemantParmar  u got the code navigationView i have added menu.xml

Comment: yes, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38519594/5110595)

Comment: yes i have look this but where i have to change i dint understand

Comment: what is dimes.xml file there no such file

Comment: @HemantParmar can we put gap do you have any idea about it

Comment: Afaik, there does **not** exist such an API. You have to create your own layout instead of using menus.

Comment: OK means using menu.xml we cant achieve this is it?