# Reduce space between menu items

Tags: android

I have the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:id="@+id/action_search_music"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_final"

        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/more_options"
        android:title="Rename playlist"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp">

        <menu >
            <item android:id="@+id/rename_playlist"
                android:title="Rename playlist"
                >
            </item>
            <item android:id = "@+id/action_delete_playlist"
                android:title="Delete playlist"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Now, there is a pretty big space between the two menu items that I am unable to reduce. Are there any ideas how to reduce that space?

**EDIT:** The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10085862/6427401 doesn't work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519293/reduce-space-between-menu-groups-inside-navigation-drawer

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar

Comment: @grant not really since the answer there is about icons sorted verically

Comment: @Kaveri the answer there doesn't work for me...

Comment: In that case, try using custom view for your action bar .

Comment: @Kaveri can you please elaborate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reduce the spacing between the Action Item Icons on Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar)

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your app theme.

```
 <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
```

where `ActionButtonStyle` is

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dip</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you look at your icons images, perhaps they have some transparent padding.
In addition, you can manipulate the menu using the Activity `onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)` function.

For example, you can make changes to the icon:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(position);
    Drawable icon = menuItem.getIcon();
    menuItem.setIcon(doSomething(icon));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom actionViewClass, either in XML or like below:

```
menuItem.setActionView(yourView);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how your code can reduce the space... icon wise - the icons are from the "image asset / vector asset" menus in Android Studio so I don't think they have a transparent padding or something similar

Comment: My code didn't change the size, just suggested where you might be able to manipulate and change your menu items. I suggest you use the Layout Inspector and that can tell you a lot about where the space is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Add next line in your styles.xml

```
<item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">5dp</item>
```

Comment: if any problem ( regarding this) you are facing so let me know Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your project dimens.xml add this line:

```
 <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by   making a custom view for your action bar. First create make the custom_actionbar.xml(layout).

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
           // Bind view like this
           // TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            //mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Note :- Using Toolbar can make customization more easy.

Hope it hepls.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the question but not every single answer solved my issue.
This helped me solved my issue.

First of all, Go to **styles.xml** file and place below add inside  TAG

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">-5dp</item> </style>
```

Next, Place below code inside your XML class(In my case it is activity_main.xml)  portion.

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Just like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me, I wanted to decrease the width of the items. th it was this combination:

```
<style name="ActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
</style>
```