# How to style menu items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-menu

I have added two items in appbar menu. But it's taking too much space to appear. How can I reduce the space between those icons and how can I change the text size?

**Menu**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/balance"
    android:title="@string/cash_wallet"
    app:showAsAction="always">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
```

**Style**

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more which space do you refer to? .. Also how many items do you want to show on the bar (i.e. not within the overflow 3 dots menu)

Comment: @Zain As you can see in the image, I want to reduce the icon padding in menu items. And I have two items to show there. To be more specific, i want to show wallet icon and wallet balance there.

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009216/reduce-space-between-menu-items