# Navigation Drawer item divider with selected background color

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a navigation drawer in my android app. Here's the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_divider"/>
```

I've used one the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview/41478759) to add dividers between the items. Here's the `nav_divider` drawable that I'm using as `itemBackground` in my `NavigationView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, the question is how do I change the background color of the selected item. I know how to do that without the divider, but with the divider, it's more complicated.

**UPDATE:**

Here's what I've tried:

I created another drawable called `nav_divider_selected` which is exactly like the `nav_divider` above except with different colors.

Then, I created a `drawer_item_background` drawable like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_divider_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_divider"/>
</selector>
```

And, replaced the `itemBackground` of the `NavigationView` with this new selector (`app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"`). But, it didn't work. The items all look black, for some reason.

Comment: do you want both the top and bottom divider to be highlighted or only the bottom, can you post a screenshot of what you want the end result should look like

Comment: I don’t want the divider to be highlighted. I want the selected item to be highlighted. I don’t think that needs a screenshot, does it?

Comment: Did you try it with a selector?

Comment: I know it should be done with a selector, but how should the selector look like?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far

Comment: @war_Hero, see my updated post.

Comment: I see that you have not the selector as the background, you should do so in the items of your layer list

Comment: @war_Hero You didn't read my update?

Comment: what happens if you set it the selector as background of the layer list items

Comment: That would be a different selector for the color. I tried that as well, but still doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, if you have an answer, I would appreciate it if you posted it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196548/discussion-between-war-hero-and-ataravati).

Comment: join if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was a simple issue. I was just using the wrong state. So, here's the solution. I created two different layer lists (to add the divider to the navigation items):

**nav_divider:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**nav_divider_selected:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_blue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then, created a `drawer_item_background` drawable like this (`state_checked` should be used not `state_selected`):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_divider_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_divider"/>
</selector>
```

And, then I used this drawable as `itemBackground` in my `NavigationView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if in-case you do not want to use a selector to achieve that you can do so like this

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            </group>
```

By wrapping the element under `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` we get a selected background.

Answer (score 0):

> Try the below item_background.xml in 
>   app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_background" for NavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/rgb_red" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/rgb_red" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item android:drawable="@color/rgb_white" />
          <item android:start="-2dp"
                android:top="-2dp"
                android:end="-2dp">
               <shape>
                 <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/rgb_pale_gray"/>
               </shape>
          </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

hope it will help you