# Divider in a NavigationView (in BottomSheetDialogFragment) doesn't shown?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a NavigationView in BottomSheetDialogFragment. But divider between groups menu doesn't appear.
I checked some solutions, for example here [How to create a simple divider in the new NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview)
But it not works for me.

nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2" />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/g_item1"
            android:title="Group Item 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/g_item2"
            android:title="Group Item 2" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/g2_item1"
            android:title="Group Item 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/g2_item2"
            android:title="Group Item 2" />
    </group>

    <item android:id="@+id/submenu"
        android:title="Sub menu" >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sub_item1"
                android:title="Sub Item 1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sub_item2"
                android:title="Sub Item 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

fragment_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BottomSheetFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/dialogFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    View view;
    public BottomSheetFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);
        NavigationView navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogFragment);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.navGraph);
                dismiss();
                return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(menuItem, navController);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Result is here

[image]

I need this result

[image]

Edited:
See result from Android Studio and from AVD

[image]

Comment: see below answer

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior because listDivider is null in the default dialog theme.

You can get your dividers to show by applying a different theme to the NavigationView like this.

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        android:id="@+id/dialogFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

use like this,if you want divider with every menu then you need to create single item with the group

Comment: I just need dividers between groups, not items

Comment: but lines are showing why it's not showing on your device

Comment: That is right question :-) I added this line to styles.xml   <item name="android:listDivider">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> for changing color of divider. See result from Android Studio and result from AVD

Comment: Maybe because it is BottomSheetDialogFragment?!